# How can you tell which version of an app is on your Android phone?

Tags: applications

I was just browsing through the AppBrain Android store and saw as one of the popular downloads Gmail.

This made me wonder how to see the version info of an application on my Galaxy S mobile phone.

How can I tell the version so that I may update this application to a new version?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to `Settings > application settings > manage application` then tap on the app. It'll say the version you are running under the name. You shouldn't have to check though; If the app in the market doesn't say "Installed" then you don't have the most recent version.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out - I am really new to Android, so I am asking basic questions. However, having gmail taken as example, the gmail application is not in this list (Twitter, Facebook and IMDB are f.i. but no gmail ) ?

Comment: @Edelcom: I'm using Samsung Galaxy S2, with Android 4.0.3. GMail can be found in Settings > Applications.

Comment: You can't assume everyone uses Google Play (Market). Some devices use Amazon App Store, or have some other store. Some don't even have an app store and require apps to be side-loaded. So it isn't always a simple matter of checking Google Play to make sure you have the most recent version.

Answer (score 8):

**Play app**

Android 5.1.1 Xperia Z3:

- find app
- permission details
- right at the top is shows:

  ```
  Version XXX can accesss
  ```

Note: this may not work for some "magic" apps, like the Play App itself.

**Device settings**

```
Settings > Apps > Downloaded > App name
```

and the version is shown at the top of the screen.

I was not able to search by the app name, so get ready for some scrolling.

Going under `Running` instead of `Downloaded` did not work: if you find your app there, it shows only runtime stats.

**adb**

Better method if you've got it setup.

Discussed at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942762/get-application-version-name-using-adb

The best command so far is:

```
adb shell dumpsys package com.google.android.apps.photos | grep versionName
```

How to get the package name: [View app's full package name?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28767/view-apps-full-package-name)

But this method is not perfect, as they can give multiple results because of the `Hidden system packages:` section.

**Feature request for Google Play Store**

Those would be ideal places for it:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play/CfSPJbhB6-k

Comment: For non Xperia Z3 users, unless your OEM deliberately changed the menu, the location would be the same i.e. "Settings > Apps > Downloaded > App name", for Android 4.x as well as 5.x.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily to settings then application settings after that choose manage application.  you will find the infomations of the [***android apps***](http://www.isoroid.com/android-apps).