# View app's full package name?

Tags: applications

I am using Android 4.0.3 and I can no longer find package name for some app. If I recall, I used to go to Applications and has been able to see it there.

So, how can I see full package name of some app? Like, the app's name is "Test" and I need to see its package `com.test.mytest`.

Answer (score 90):

**Edit:** I like [ofir_aghai's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/199965/5132) better, although my answer may still be helpful for apps that aren't on the Google Play Store.

If you're comfortable using the command line, a solution I like is Android's pm command. It can easily be called using [adb](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) like so:

```
$ adb shell "pm list packages -f test"
package:/system/app/AutomationTest_JBUP.apk=com.sec.android.app.DataCreate
package:/system/app/BluetoothTest.apk=com.sec.android.app.bluetoothtest
```

Replace `test` with whatever package you're looking for.

pm has a variety of options that may be useful depending what you want to do:

```
usage: pm list packages [-f] [-d] [-e] [-s] [-3] [-i] [-u] [FILTER]
pm list packages: prints all packages, optionally only
  those whose package name contains the text in FILTER.  Options:
    -f: see their associated file.
    -d: filter to only show disbled packages.
    -e: filter to only show enabled packages.
    -s: filter to only show system packages.
    -3: filter to only show third party packages.
    -i: see the installer for the packages.
    -u: also include uninstalled packages.
```

Comment: This works perfect. As a generic solution, this seems to be the correct answer for the question. Also we can use `grep` if we know some part of the package name.

Comment: @gnuanu Yes, I used grep at first and then I realized the -f flag does the same thing (filters by package name), as you can see in the example. Either works fine.

Comment: If you are on Windows, use double quotes `"` instead of single quotes `'`. Like this: `adb shell "pm list packages -f test"` Or you will get weird errors.

Comment: This doesn't work if the full name of the app or apk file does not contain the displayed name of the app. e.g. "Google Play Services" is com.google.android.gms, but this is basically impossible to find

Comment: It's saying `/data/app/br.org.academia.volp-…` but there's no `app` directory inside `/data`. Why?

Comment: @Rodrigo folders inside `/data` need root access to browse. (To be clear, the location of APK files, either system apps or user apps, cannot be accessed without root access.)

Answer (score 19):

Just share the app from Google Play Store to somewhere,  (by clicking on the share button in the app's page)
and see the shared value.

You will see something like:
`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.my.packagename`
(note: this app doesn't exist, it is only used as an example)

(If you can't find it in Google Play: 
You can long press on app icon and press on "Application info"
Go to the bottom of the Android page, and then click on "App details in store")

Answer (score 10):

You can look into the LogCat.

1. Open the LogCat.

   - Either in Eclipse or on the cmd line if the device is connected to your PC.
   - Or on your mobile itself, using any app which allows you to view LogCat.
2. Once LogCat is available, launch the app.

   The log corresponding to **"ActivityManager"** will display the activity started. It will usually be in the format: `"Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]..."`.

However technical this approach might be, this is - IMHO - the best way to achieve knowledge about the launching activity for any of the installed apps.

Answer (score 5):

Many apps can show the package name of the installed apps. I'm suggesting [App Manager](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/io.github.muntashirakon.AppManager/) (available on F-Droid) which I currently use. Search the app name or the package name, and the the relevant entries would start showing up.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you are proficient at using `adb` and Linux you can find it pretty quick using the linux command `grep`.

Just do:

```
adb shell
ls -al /data/data/ | grep 'yourAppName'
```

You need root of course to be able to search in `/data/data/`

Comment: So how do I become root? Root as in Linux root or root as in "root" your device?

Comment: @NelsonGon "Rooting your device" means "gaining the ability to become `root` on the device". As such, in order to become `root`, your device must, by definition, be rooted.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD). It can list apps by name and show package names and other useful info.

Answer (score 2):

- You can search for the app's name in the Play Store and open that app. Now look into the URL. The last part of the URL is the package name, like `id=com.google`.
- You can use `adb shell` and execute `pm list packages -f`. There are many operators, look into it. If you do not find all packages, then use `dumpsys package` command.

  On Oppo mobile, `pm list packages` provide me with 150 entries while `dumpsys package` provide me with 163 entries.
- You can use an Android package name viewer application.

Comment: pm and dumpsys commands do list package names but how does one go around knowing which one belongs to the app of interest? Not all developers add app label in package name, so it is not obvious to guess.

Answer (score 1):

Use [App Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager) app. It has plenty of features: sorting, filtering, finding, managing APK files, showing removed apps (since the time you've installed the app), root operations, and handling various split-APK files (APKS, APKM, XAPK) right from file manager apps.

Disclosure: I made the app.

Answer (score 1):

On the phone, you can use [Package Name Viewer 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.csdroid.pkg).

You can browse through installed apps or search by app name.