# How to run a specific app's action via terminal?

Tags: applications, terminal, command-line

I need to run my Android app from a remote computer via SSH, but I'm not a command-line expert.

So I would like to know: how to run a **specific action** (not just open) of an app? Which implies: how to KNOW the exact syntax of possible actions of an app?

Example: I want to start an audio-recording app on my phone from my computer, AND start recording from a remote. Is it possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use this:

```
am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n <package_name>/<full_class_name>
```

To control an app, you'll have to put correct values of `<package_name>` and `<full_class_name>` in the command. For example, you can use `com.google.gmail/com.google.gmail.check_mail` (Hypothetical names) as last part of command.

[Obtaining package name of an app is easy](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28767/view-apps-full-package-name), but obtaining class name of action isn't. There are two problems:

1. Many app developers keep class info private.
2. Not all developers do smart modular programming. Its good habit to divide an app in multiple classes which could be triggered by intents, but not all developers are smart.

Solution of 1st problem: Decompile the app using [apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) and see all info. There are also other ways, but this one is always-working method (unless app is based on NDK instead of SDK).

Solution of 2nd problem: Nothing.

Don't worry, most of popular apps follow best programming practice and they provide `Public API` from which you can get class info.

Comment: @Izzy Here's my problem: I'm unable to launch this Activity of Settings app: `com.android.settings/.Settings$StorageSettingsActivity`. Try it yourself. Actually, what is that string after `$` sign ? Is it like a sub-class in the Settings activity?

Comment: @GokulNC you might need to quote the entire thing (single quotes), or `$StorageSettingsActivity` might be seen as a variable and "expanded" to an empty string (unless there's a variable defined by that name).

Comment: Ooh, I didn't even realize that.. Thanks BTW :)

Answer (score 9):

Like Sachin Shekhar said, you must use the following command :

```
am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n <package_name>/<full_class_name>
```

See a concrete example :

- getting the apk file from your Android device or any Market places
- running this command :

`aapt dump xmltree com.android.settings*.apk AndroidManifest.xml`

I would like to start "tethering" menu, so I search an activity in the output :

```
(...)
   E: activity (line=190)
    A: android:name(0x01010003)=".TetherSettings" (Raw: ".TetherSettings")
(...)
```

So the final command is :

```
am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.TetherSettings
```

The `aapt` command is part of the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

Comment: Just `.TetherSettings` in the command wouldn't work. Its not FULL class name..

Comment: No, you can ommit the `com.android.settings` PATH, that's why I said it's relative. Test it on any app you'd like.

Comment: I didn't say that it'll not work with other apps. The dot before class name does the magic. But, this shouldn't be encouraged.

Comment: You said that's luck, this is not. Do you have sources for your assertion ? Why this shouldn't be encouraged ?

Comment: For an Android developer, its certainly not luck. But, on broad scale, I'd say Android supports relative paths by the luck of user. This shouldn't be encouraged to non-developers due to error prone nature.

Answer (score 0):

Use a general purpose logging app (just search logcat on playstore). The logs should show you the app name, class and intent.
Following that run the command in an adb shell or from inside a terminal application in your device:

```
am start -a <intent> -n <class>
```

Comment: Could you expand the answer? Suppose I have gotten the app name, class, and intent from the logcat, then what should I do to "run a specific app's action via terminal" (as per the OP's main question)?