# SSH server on Android Emulator

Tags: android-emulator, ssh

Is it possible to start SSH server on Android emulator? What is the app name? I've tried a few apps but neither of them could run on Emulator.

Comment: Have you checked [how to run a specific app's action via terminal?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/30098/16575)

Comment: What do you think is special about the emulator with respect to an SSH server? When you used a search engine to search for `android ssh server`, and found various open source ones, and tried them in the emulator, what did you learn?

Comment: They all want to have WiFi on device. All of them fail on emulator. I've tried to disable WiFi check but then they kind of run but do not work.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you have networking set up for your emulator, you might need to forward your SSH port from the emulator to a port on the host. Your emulator might be set up on a NAT/host-only network, so your SSH client can't actually reach the server.

To test this, try pinging the emulator's IP address from the system with your SSH client.