# Mi Max 2 Xiaomi apps as default immutable setting

Tags: browser, hardware, default-applications, xiaomi

I'm using a Xiaomi Mi Max 2 phone.
At the last time I was able to open links with a browser of my choice. But now, the "browser" only is imposed. Additionally, there is a lot of Xiaomi tools and apps that appeared, as App Vault, shortcuts and calendar from Xiaomi that take the control of my phone.
How can I get there out?

Comment: You might be able to disable them. See https://android.stackexchange.com/q/56620/96277

Comment: Thanks, but my phone is not rootable @Firelord