# How to permanently disable or remove preinstalled apps?

Tags: applications, accounts

I have an older Google Nexus 4 (by LG), running 5.1.1 Lollipop (latest supported version). I want this to be my daughters first smartphone, and want to lock it down as much as possible.

So besides my own user account on the device I created a second user account for her. I installed the apps she should be able to use, but want to restrict others.

So I went on and disabled all apps she should not be able to use.
However, all disabled apps keep re-appearing on her account after a day or so.

I went on and disabled automatic app updates on my own user and on her account, then went on and again disabled all apps on her account, but they keep re-appearing.

Question is: How can I permanently remove apps (especially the pre-installed apps like YouTube, Google, News, GMail, Hangouts, Play Books Play Music etc.) from her user account?

Rooting the device is not an option.

Comment: See if my answer helps. Check the non-root section. https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208271/96277

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

1. Connect device via ADB
2. Go to ADB shell

   ```
   adb shell
   ```
3. Find your target app by listing all the apps

   ```
   pm list packages
   ```
4. Remove app like this

   ```
   pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.android.inputdevices
   ```