# Messages from other android users not registering

Tags: sms

I've noticed that my galaxy s10 has problmes processing(might not be the correct term) messages from other android users. First, if im using my galaxy buds, it will skip reading messages from other android users. Second, KDE connect will not register new messages from android users. This is frustrating. Appreciate any help.

EDIT: Is there a way to treat android to android messages like regular SMS, as opposed to having the read receipt and blue indicator dots on? I think that is messing with everything.

Comment: use the default sms app

Comment: I am, is there anyway to disable the advanced messaging stuff

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/56620 https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/default-applications/info

Comment: i have similar problem with textra https://android.stackexchange.com/q/214283