# How to recompile existing Android ROM without certain packages

Tags: rom

I want to be able to take any version of Android ROM from any device, decompile it, remove certain packages (browser, Google Play, etc), and then recompile it, just without those packages. So it would be the exact same, but those packages would not be part of the new version of Android ROM.

How could I do that?

Comment: Do don't need to decompile or recompile anything. As you need an bootloader unlocked device (otherwise you can not modify anything on the system) you can boot into a custom recovery ROM that allows you to modify the system partition, or you root the phone then you can modify it from within Android itself. Note that deleting system packages can brick your system (and then requires a fresh installation of a working ROM).

Comment: That sounds super complicated - I have to figure out how to do that.

Comment: @Robert Where would be a good place to start learning how to do that?

Comment: As  good a place to start as any is with the Android Documentation i.e. https://source.android.com/setup/build/building

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable and disable system apps via ADB](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56620/enable-and-disable-system-apps-via-adb)