# Cannot uninstall apps that are not system apps, but downloaded from the play store

Tags: applications, uninstallation

I am unable to uninstall apps like Amazon Shopping and Call Guardian from my Android phone although they are non-essential and were downloaded from the Google Play Store. I can only disable them as with system apps.

Does anyone know why this is or how they can be uninstalled?

Comment: Check for Device Administrator rights associated with the apps in question. On a Samsung device, see 'Other Security settings'. Other brands, similar naming.

Comment: If there's nothing on Device Administrator, then some 3rd-party apps might have been installed as system apps by the vendor (i.e. bloatware). If that's the case, then you can try [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/246022/44325).

Comment: If you can disable them then they are pre-installed apps you can't delete. Deinstalling is them is everything you need to do. You don't get any advantage for really uninstalling such an app (which would require root permissions).

Comment: I was gonna suggest a factory reset, but don't forget to backup anything important