# How to prevent apps for second user showing in list of apps for first user?

Tags: settings, apk, rom, development

How can I make sure that the apps in my secondary space don't appear in the list of apps in my primary profile? I would like it to appear only the installed apps according to active space, I looked for commits or instructions to edit this behavior in the settings APK but I can't find it, this behavior is very common in ROMs on Android 11, in others most are fixed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Via adb there are a lot of package manger `pm` commands available (see e.g. https://android.stackexchange.com/q/56620/2241). A lot of those commands can be restricted to a certain user account like `--user 0` so you have a number of commands you can test.