# Unchecking the "show notifications" for the Phone app

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, 4.2-jelly-bean, root-access

My carrier keeps sending the voicemail notification to my device. I can force-stop the phone app (makes the notifications go away), but EVERY SINGLE TIME the device reboots or do something phone-related, **boom**, its back.

In the app info, the checkbox for notifications is shaded.

Is there any way to make the checkbox unmarked?

I have root, terminal emulator and ADB to play with.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've root access, you can easily allow or ignore the notifications of any app.

1. Install a file manager having root explorer feature such as [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) or [MiXplorer](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1523691).
2. Go to `/data/system` and open `notification-policy.xml`.
3. Add `<package name"PKG_NAME" />` between `<blocked-packages>` and `</blocked-packages>`, such as:

   <sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

   [image: IMG:]

   Replace `PKG_NAME` with the package name of the app whose notifications you don't want to see. See [View app's full package name?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28767/view-apps-full-package-name#)
4. Save the file and reboot the device. The "Show notifications" checkbox would now be seen unticked.

   [image: IMG:]
   [image: IMG:]

There's also an alternative approach which didn't work for me. You may give it a try though. Find it [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/120417/96277).