# "Show notifications" is greyed out for some apps. What's causing it and how do I change it?

Tags: applications, notifications

There are some apps for which "Show Notifications" is greyed out, thus effectively barring you from changing the notification policy of that app.

1. Why or when does it happen?
2. I've noticed this issue for system apps only? Does it mean that only system apps can have this option greyed out?
3. How do I change the notification policy for such apps?

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

I have a rooted Android 4.2.1, 4.4.2 and 5.0.2. I'm aware of changing the notification policy in Android 4.2.1 and 4.4.2. You may move the focus to Lollipop, only for third point.

Comment: Related: [Unchecking the "show notifications" for the Phone app](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/83076)

Comment: There are some [apps for notification settings](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_settings#group_543), some of them claiming to be capable of that. I've not tested any, so I cannot say for sure.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for the link. Using `notifications_policy.xml` in Android 4.2 and 4.4, I can  easily disable app notifications for any of the app regardless of that greyed out check-box, so I don't have to rely on third-party apps. But the issue is more conceptual, the reason I asked three questions under one hood.

Comment: Ah, so you've got a partial solution already – but look for a final one :) Well, I'm not aware on any not requiring a 3rd party app (which you surely would prefer). If there's really no such, feel free to post your answer with an app from my list, if you found a satisfying candidate. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jan's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/120417/44325) already addresses how to change the notification policy for such (disabled "show notifications") apps.

As for why and when (or essentially, in what condition it applies), your guess of system apps is on the right track.

To be exact, as [Sergey has explained in the comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/120169/show-notifications-is-greyed-out-for-some-apps-whats-causing-it-and-how-do-i/120420?noredirect=1#comment148945_120420), only packages that are signed with the `platform` key (from vendor/manufacturer, e.g. [AOSP](https://github.com/android/platform_build/tree/master/target/product/security)) will have this privilege. These packages are [part of the core platform](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/sign_builds.html#certificates-keys). Other preinstalled apps (including apps with some special privileges, which are signed with the `shared` or `media` key) and "system" apps (apps which are put on `/system/app` folder and granted access right) are not counted.

Summary: as of the latest version (Android 5.1.1 Lollipop), the checkbox is disabled if:

1. The app is signed with `platform` key (part of the core platform), or
2. The app is not installed on the current user (in multi-user case)

---

From [InstalledAppDetails.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/lollipop-mr1-release/src/com/android/settings/applications/InstalledAppDetails.java#410) (this is what "App Info" displays),

```
private CompoundButton mNotificationSwitch; // this is the "show notifications" checkbox

...

private void initNotificationButton() {

    ...

    if (Utils.isSystemPackage(mPm, mPackageInfo)) {
        mNotificationSwitch.setEnabled(false);
    } else if ((mPackageInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_INSTALLED) == 0) {
        // App is not installed on the current user
        mNotificationSwitch.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        mNotificationSwitch.setEnabled(true);
        mNotificationSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }
}
```

**Note**:

- `Utils.isSystemPackage()` returns `true` only for packages signed with the `platform` key.
- This doesn't apply on Android 6.0 Marshmallow due to overhaul on App Info's user interface; there's no checkbox, instead there's a centralized notification settings per app. However, the underlying principle is still the same that you cannot block notifications on an app that [is system package](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/marshmallow-release/src/com/android/settings/notification/AppNotificationSettings.java#222).

Comment: Thanks for the link. But in My Paranoid and RR Rom some system apps like HTML viewer, Launcher, Download and more doesn't have that option greyed out. It would be much appreciated if a bit more reasoning concerning my point 1 and 2 is provided.

Comment: @Firelord `Utils.isSystemPackage()` returns `true` only for packages signed by the `platform` key, which should be used [only for packages which are part of the core platform](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/sign_builds.html#certificates-keys). Other preinstalled apps (including apps with some special privileges, which are signed with the `shared` or `media` key) are not considered as “system” apps here.

Answer (score 4):

With root access, there are some apps such as [3c Toolbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ccc71.at.free) that allow you to change the notification settings for any app. [App Ops](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.findsdk.apppermission) is another one that gives you control over all apps' general permissions.

You can actually manage all app permissions from the command line with root access. In Android 5.x, `appops` was added. It gives control over general app permissions.

Find your app's package name by looking through the list generated by:

```
# pm list packages | sed 's/^package://'
```

Get a list of permissions and their `mode` (allow/ignore/deny/default) for a particular app:

(Note that `get` parameter is not available in [5.0.2](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/com/android/commands/appops/AppOpsCommand.java?av=f) or earlier Lollipop releases, but was introduced in  Android [5.1.0](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.0_r1/com/android/commands/appops/AppOpsCommand.java?av=f))

```
# appops get <package_name>
```

Set a particular app's permission:

```
# appops set <package_name> <permission> <mode>
```

**To accomplish the same thing as unticking the "show notifications" box in the application manager:**

```
# appops set <package_name> POST_NOTIFICATION ignore
```

From my experience, using `deny` as a `mode` can break appops so that permissions can't be accessed or changed from an app, so I recommend using `ignore`, which is what the system uses.

If in some case, you end up breaking access to app ops through something like the application manager, you can reset the permissions for an app:

```
appops reset <package_name>
```

---

For more control over detailed permissions, you can use `pm` in the terminal. This works with older Android versions.

Find your app's package name by looking through the list generated by:

```
# pm list packages | sed 's/^package://'
```

Then list the permissions for a particular package:

```
# pm list permissions <package_name>
```

Find the notifcation permissions:

```
# pm list permissions <package_name> | grep NOTIF
```

Grant or revoke a particular permission:

```
# pm grant <package_name> <permission>
# pm revoke <package_name> <permission>
```

The permissions listed with package manager are very detailed. Using a capable app to manage them may be a more practical route.

Comment: Hi! I added some info about `get` parameter availability  because it was confusing me since Android 5.0.2 or any 5.0.x release doesn't have it. Feel free to rollback, but why would you? :)

Comment: Jan, how do you revoke an app's ability to show a toast in Android 4.4.2? Unlike 4.2.1 Kitkat has `appops.xml` but doesn't have the binary `appops` for us to do anything with that file. And changing that file does nothing even after reboot. I'm interested in this [question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/125043/96277). See if you can help there or at least here. Thanks!

Comment: @Firelord, thanks for making that modification. I wasn't aware of the appops difference between Lollipop versions. Also, I went ahead and posted to the link you provided [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/125043/how-can-i-disable-android-permission-manager-notification/125199#125199). It got a little to long to post as a comment.