# Is there any way to turn off/on a grayed out notification from an app through an ADB command?

Tags: adb, notifications, settings, phone-app

My default phone/call app doesn't allow me to turn off notifications.

When I go into the 'Apps and notifications' and find the phone/call app and try to turn them off, the switch is grayed out and does not allow me to.

Is there any ADB command I can do to overwrite this and allow me to control the notification?

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts. Just in case it's relevant, could you [edit] and also mention the device model and Android version?

Comment: Try this answer: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/120417/96277