# What is Launcher3 4.4.4-9 application?

Tags: permissions

I'm new Android user. I just found that I have "Launcher3 4.4.4-9" on my Moto G 2-gen.

It has permissions to make calls. I cannot uninstall it.

Is this normal? This is system app/service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [F-Droid wiki](https://f-droid.org/wiki/page/com.android.launcher3),

> Name: Launcher3
>
> ID: com.android.launcher3
>
> **Description**
>
> ---
>
> Android 4.4 homescreen from AOSP ...

The version (4.4.4-9) also confirms that it is the Android KitKat (4.4.4) AOSP Launcher. It's normal and it's a system app.

Comment: Where can I see app ID? Can't find it in KitKat.

Comment: Please read [View app's full package name](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28767/view-apps-full-package-name) for further info.

Comment: It's especially confusing, because the app icon is pixel art and looks outdated. https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CJbVqSiUAAAwk0R.jpg