# What is the APK (and package) name of the Google App?

Tags: apk, google

On my Android 4.1.2 I can see force stop, uninstall updates, clear data, clear cache and view permissions of my installed apps via `Settings` > `Manage apps` but I am unable to tell their APK and/or package name.

I am particularly interested in knowing the name of the [Google App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox&hl=en) (that's the name appearing next to its icon in App info). Its latest version as downloaded from Google Play just now is `4.1.24.1672412.arm`.

Is there a way to get its APK name and package name?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answering my own question, thanks to the method found on this [View app's full package name?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/72942/91216) thread and the hint provided by Google App's URL in Google play.

I typed:

```
 adb shell 'pm list packages -f searchbox'
```

And received:

```
package:/data/app/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox-1.apk=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
```

Answer (score 3):

To see the actual package name of the Google App installed on your device, connect to a PC, enable USB debugging, download the adb source from https://developer.google.com and run the following commands.

1. launch the adb Shell: `adb shell`
2. Show a list of all the packages: `pm list packages`

Scroll through the list of packages, you should see `package: com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox` which is the package name for the Google App.

Alternatively, you can install an application called [Activity Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.szalkowski.activitylauncher&hl=en&gl=US) on the device, it will also display the package names for you.