# Why Do I have multiple dirs in /data/app

Tags: internal-storage

I noticed that I was short on space so I checked with a disk analyser app.

I noticed that I have 8 instances of `com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox-1` in `/data/app` and each dir is about 130 MB.

The number at the end increments.

Is this 1 app or 8 versions of the same one?

Can I delete all but one?  Which do I keep?

Answer (score 1):

This is the package name of *Google App* as explained here [What is the APK (and package) name of the Google App?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/96648/131553)

I am not sure why there should be multiple entries unless the app has been frequently updated and older versions have incremented numbers at end

In any case, you can check which is the latest using any root explorer (I use [Solid explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.solidexplorer2)) to check properties of `base.apk` retaining the newest one ( which should correspond to the one having `-1` at end, that being the package name )

[image]

Comment: +1. OP, there shouldn't be multiple copies (updates) of one app coexisting in there. Whenever an app upgrades that number increments on the existing folder, instead of generating a new one. Delete the ones that aren't currently in use.