# data/app folder showing wrong folder names

Tags: cyanogenmod, 5.0-lollipop, file-system, oneplus-one, xposed-framework

After messing around with the xposed framework and installing lots of modules, I got into a bootloop (classic !), but I knew the solution was to add a `disabled` file in `data/app/de.rovb.android.xposed.installer/conf/` to disable xposed and uninstall the faulty modules.

The thing is, most of the time when I access this folder, I don't see the correct folder names, which are supposed to look like this : `com.xyz.app.*`. Instead, I see `com.xyz.app.*-1` folders, containing a `lib` folder and the app's `.apk` file. I have to reboot into recovery a dozen times before I can access the actual folders.

I'm running CyanogenMod 12S (5.0.2) on a (rooted) OnePlus One.

I have no idea what's happening, and I couldn't find any info on that. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Doesn't xposed come with a zip that needs to be flashed from recovery to disable that? It is installed in your SD when you install Xposed

Comment: @beeshyams that would "uninstall" the framework (i.e. revert the patches completely). I've not heard of the method Danish describes here (in fact, googling for *"data/app/de.rovb.android.xposed.installer/conf/" disabled* just turns up this post here), but could imagine it somehow just sets the framework "inactive" on boot – however that's supposed to work. What makes me doubt that (probably a typo): `/data/app` usually contains the `.apk` files only, no subdirs. Meant is probably [`/data/data/...`](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=59863171&postcount=4978).

Comment: @izzy. Thanks. I was on lines of disabling framework, remove all modules and add incrementally since he didn't specify if he knew which module is creating trouble.  Methods suggested by you and //firelord  are beyond me

Comment: @Firelord yes, yes, you're right ! my bad.
@Izzy this method exists, you just need to navigate to `data/data/de.robv.android.xposed.installer/conf/` and add that `disabled` file.

Comment: @DanishAshfaq yes, that's what I've pointed out. Your question has `/data/app`, which should be `/data/data`. And according to the XDA post I've linked, the file name is `disable`, not `disabled`. Another typo?

Comment: @Izzy, for the filename, it's not a typo. I verified (on Android 4.2.1 and 5.0.2) that if you put a blank file named `disabled` (not `disable`) under `conf/` the Xposed Framework doesn't activate any modules.

Comment: @Firelord thanks! So it was another typo – but this time at the other end :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's clear up some confusion. Things to always remember:

- `/data/app` contains the APK of an app.

  <sub>(PACKAGE → [package name of an app](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28767/view-apps-full-package-name))</sub>

  - Android 4.x: if the app is installed using Package installer of Android the file name would be `PACKAGE-*.apk` where * is often a positive integer.

    `/data/app` isn't supposed to have any directory inside it.
  - Android 5.x: if the app is installed using the Package installer, a directory would be created for the app with name `PACKAGE-*` where * is often a positive integer. This directory contains the APK of the app with name `base.apk`.
- For both Android 4.x and 5.x, `/data/data` contains only the data of the apps. All the apps are allotted a directory with name *strictly* the package name of the app.
- For both Android 4.x and 5.x, `/data/lib` contains only the library (optional) of the apps. All the apps are allotted a directory with name `PACKAGE-*` where * is often a positive integer.

Now let's head towards the real issue.

---

When dealing with boot issues caused by an Xposed module, do not wander here and there.

**Note:**

- Device requires to be booted into a custom recovery, data partition mounted there and [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) setup in PC.
- PACKAGE → package name of the Xposed module here
- Unless explicitly mentioned otherwise, the solution would work on Android versions 4.2.1 - 5.1.1.

### When you know which module is causing the boot issue

Go to `/data/app` and remove the APK of the troublesome module. This can be done from GUI on TWRP.

You can use command-line as an alternative

```
adb shell rm /data/app/PACKAGE*.apk
```

A less-extreme approach is to disable the Xposed module but not remove it. Head over to data directory of Xposed Installer `/data/data/de.robv.android.xposed.installer`, go inside `conf`, and remove the entry for your module from `modules.list`. It is up to you how you remove the line.

- You can pull the file into PC, make changes and push it back.
- I'd go for command-line though

  ```
  adb shell sed -i '/.*PACKAGE.*/d' /data/data/de.robv.android.xposed.installer/conf/modules.list
  ```

  `sed` is a stream editor and it is removing any line which contains module's package name from `modules.list`.

### When uncertain about the exact module causing the boot issue

- Go to to data directory of Xposed Installer `/data/data/de.robv.android.xposed.installer`, go inside `conf`, and remove or rename or revoke read permission from `modules.list`.
- Alternatively, create a blank file named `disabled` (not `disable`) inside `conf` directory. This would cause Xposed Framework to not activate any module during boot. You can create the file using command-line

  ```
  adb shell touch /data/data/de.robv.android.xposed.installer/conf/disabled
  ```
- [Another alternative](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=51306764&postcount=9879), per the framework's developer rovo89 is

  > [It is] possible to disable Xposed by **repeatedly pressing one of the hardware buttons during early startup**. The phone will vibrate twice when the first key press has been detected. Then you have five seconds to press the same button four more times. Each key press will be confirmed with a short vibration; the final one with a long vibration. It creates `/data/data/de.robv.android.xposed.installer/conf/disabled`, which prevents most of Xposed's actions (e.g. ... no modules are loaded). There's no 100% guarantee that this will get you out of a bootloop, but in most cases it should.

  <sub>(Emphasis mine)</sub>

## Remove Xposed Framework as a last resort

#### Android 4.2.x - 4.4.x

Use the file [`Xposed-Disabler-Recovery.zip`](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=52632524&postcount=5) located at `/sdcard/Android/data/de.robv.android.xposed.installer/files`. Flash that file from recovery mode to disable  Xposed Framework. It doesn't delete the Installer app.

Download the file from [official thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/xposed-installer-versions-changelog-t2714053), if you don't have one.

That archive, in essence, changes `/system/bin/app_process.orig` to `/system/bin/app_process`. You can make those changes on your own using adb in recovery mode.

#### Android 5.x

The [official thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811) hosts an uninstaller file. Download the one relevant to your CPU's architecture and flash it from recovery mode.

If you're not using the official Xposed Framework then the uninstaller may not work for you. It may even cause unforeseen issues. Best is to search the web for the uninstaller.