# How to "completely" delete Xposed Framework and modules?

Tags: xposed-framework

I did two things to install Xposed. Firstly, I flashed `xposed-v75-sdk21-x86.zip` and then installed the .apk file. I can now uninstall the app itself but how can I erase the flashed file of the .zip?

Also, where are the modules stored? How to delete the modules completely?

Device is LG G3 D855. Running on Cloudy G3 ROM.

Comment: Can you please specify which device and OS you're using? I ask because I'm using Xposed on my Galaxy S3 and everything, including modules, installed and uninstalled as third-party apps using the native app installer. So I'm not understanding the difference in how your Xposed is set up. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't a `.zip` file be flashed first? I just followed the instructions.

Comment: Which instructions? I used information from the [Xposed Installer](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) site which has an apk to download and install. I didn't flash anything to get mine to work. Again, might be different on your device.

Comment: [Here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811). It is the framework itself I assume and the app is just the manager.

Comment: Okay, although I don't think I'm the one to help with this, we're getting somewhere. You should edit the tags in your question to include your OS since this apparently makes a difference with how Xposed is installed. KitKat=apk install, Lolipop and Marshmallow=zip to flash.

Comment: I actually figured it out I think. I figured where to find the installed stuff. Where are the modules are downloaded at though?

Comment: First, I've never "flashed" anything to install the framework – the installer takes care for that. Second, the modules are just like normal apps – so you'll most likely find them in `/data/app`. Cannot tell for 100% that covers all, but those I know do.

Comment: @Izzy Can you read the xda thread I mentioned on my comment? It tells to flash. Why so?

Comment: Uh… Maybe it's different for Lollipop and Marshmallow. I'm still running it on Kitkat. If Rovo wrote flash, then flash it is. Sorry, I totally forgot about the differences introduced by Lollipop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** provided that you end up at this post in search of solving the bootloop issue caused by an Xposed module, my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/130731/96277) would better help you .

---

## For any Android Lollipop

> I can now uninstall the app itself but how can I erase the flashed file of the .zip?

See the attached files in the first post of [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811). In relevance to your device's CPU architecture, download the uninstaller archive and flash it from the custom recovery. It would undo the  changes the installer archive made.

In essence, the installer archive keeps the original system files but appends in their name `.orig`  or convert them into archives (unofficial installers do). It then places its modified files at their location. All uninstaller does is remove the modified and extra files and change the backed up files back to their original self.

Relevant section from the uninstaller script

```
echo "- Restoring/removing files"
rm -f /system/xposed.prop
rm -f /system/framework/XposedBridge.jar

restore_link   /system/bin/app_process32               0 2000 0755 u:object_r:zygote_exec:s0
restore_backup /system/bin/dex2oat                     0 2000 0755 u:object_r:dex2oat_exec:s0
restore_backup /system/bin/oatdump                     0 2000 0755
restore_backup /system/bin/patchoat                    0 2000 0755 u:object_r:dex2oat_exec:s0
restore_backup /system/lib/libart.so                   0    0 0644
restore_backup /system/lib/libart-compiler.so          0    0 0644
restore_backup /system/lib/libart-disassembler.so      0    0 0644
restore_backup /system/lib/libsigchain.so              0    0 0644
restore_backup /system/lib/libxposed_art.so            0    0 0644
if [ $IS64BIT ]; then
  restore_link   /system/bin/app_process64             0 2000 0755 u:object_r:zygote_exec:s0
  restore_backup /system/lib64/libart.so               0    0 0644
  restore_backup /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so      0    0 0644
  restore_backup /system/lib64/libart-disassembler.so  0    0 0644
  restore_backup /system/lib64/libsigchain.so          0    0 0644
  restore_backup /system/lib64/libxposed_art.so        0    0 0644
fi
```

If you've the knowledge of setting the appropriate SELinux context for a file in Android from recovery mode, you can simply map the files the installer would've changed, revert the changes using command-line and set the correct context. No uninstaller would be required.

**Note:** If you're not using the official Xposed Framework then the uninstaller may not work for you. It may even cause unforeseen issues. Best is to search the web for the uninstaller.

> Also, where are the modules stored?

- Xposed Installer app downloads the modules under `/sdcard/Download`.
- They may be called modules [but they simply are apps to Android](https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/wiki/Development-tutorial#creating-the-project), hence the APK would be found under `/data/app` or the locations covered [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/28231/96277) by Izzy. Alike every app, there data directory would be found under `/data/data`.

> How to delete the modules completely?

Deleting an Xposed  module is no different than removing any user installed app from Android. So, you can use any technique that you would use to remove an ordinary app.

Note that the file `XposedBridge.jar` under `/system/framework/` is what provides modules the necessary APIs to interact with the modified framework.

---

## For Android 4.2.x - 4.4.x

Use the file [`Xposed-Disabler-Recovery.zip`](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=52632524&postcount=5) located at `/sdcard/Android/data/de.robv.android.xposed.installer/files`. Flash that file from recovery mode (requires a custom recovery) to disable Xposed Framework. If you don't have such file, download it from the first post of the [official thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/xposed-installer-versions-changelog-t2714053).

That archive, in essence, changes `/system/bin/app_process.orig` to `/system/bin/app_process` i.e. it removes the modified `app_process` and brings the original file back to its glory. It doesn't delete the Installer app. You can make those changes on your own too using adb in recovery mode.

The concept of modules here is no different from what is covered in the above section.

Answer (score 1):

Until KitKat, to disable the framework you need to flash this zip (stored on your `/sd` at installation **Xposed-Disabler-Recovery.zip** .

As far as uninstalling the modules goes, selecting *Modules*, (from installer), long pressing the module(s) to be removed does it in KitKat. Of course, changes take place after reboot, and I am assuming the same holds for higher versions of Android. Modules reside as per [Izzy's comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/131236/how-to-completely-delete-xposed-framework-and-modules/131294#comment163939_131236) for KitKat.

Quoting extracts from [How to Uninstall Xposed Framework on Android Lollipop Guides Aug 21, 2015](http://www.droidviews.com/how-to-uninstall-xposed-framework-on-android-lollipop/):

> Xposed Framework on Lollipop needs to be installed manually through a Custom Recovery unlike in Jelly Bean and Kitkat where the Xposed installer apk file would install the framework on your system automatically. So uninstalling Xposed Framework on Lollipop would require you to flash an **Xposed Uninstaller Script using a Custom Recovery like TWRP or CWM.**... Take note that **Xposed Uninstaller are different for different devices like arm, arm64, x86.** Find the Uninstaller Script for your device in the Downloads section. Also, Uninstaller Scripts are different for Android versions 5.0 (SDK 21) and 5.1 (SDK 22).

It further provides uninstall instructions and scripts.

I am on KitKat and have no way of testing this. It was a coincidence reading this and later seeing your question.