# Where Recent Apps specific files are stored?

Tags: 7.1-nougat, xposed-framework, recents-screen

Android 7.1. Messed up with «Eternal Process Lock», the xposed module. Activated its features, but forgot to activate the module. Now recent apps stopped working, reboot doesn't help, activating/reactivating module/features too. However, I can ask the community who use the same model to share their system files. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Xposed modules do not make permanent changes, so you should be able to fix this problem by removing that module using a custom recovery. See https://android.stackexchange.com/q/131236/96277

Comment: I tried to disable xposed completely – it didn't help. Unfortunately, I have bootlocked phone, so I can use only root options without recovery.