# LG G3 Resolution messed up - how to stop processes on startup?

Tags: applications, cyanogenmod, boot, processes

I'm running CM 12.1 on an LG G3 (VS985) with TWRP recovery.

I used an app called UI Tuner to change my resolution, thinking that it would revert back to normal after 15 seconds.. well it didn't. It crashed? when I did it, and then it started back up? with the super low resolution.

Now I'm stuck with a screen that's like 200x300 and the DPI is wayy off, so I can't really use the screen.

I used TWRP to manually delete the app, but the problem persists. The reason it doesn't just reset my resolution upon startup is because I had it set to change my resolution to 1920x1080 for better performance on startup. Is there a way to stop it from running on startup? I have access to TWRP still, and I can sorta do very limited things within my phone, but it's so small that all I can do is open apps and see the very tops of them.

I tried looking for a way to manually stop apps from running on startup, but all I can find are guides on how to use apps that you install.. which doesn't help at all.
I really would like to keep my current apps and setup and everything. I almost resorted to just flashing a new ROM, but I really don't want to do that.
I tried using ADB, but it says that there's no device found. I'm pretty sure I had USB debugging on, so I don't know why it can't find my phone... although I can't really see it to tell if it's on or not.

Comment: You can delete the app with TWRP. Are you sure you have done it correctly?

Comment: See if my [answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/131556/96277) helps. You may try [my answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/112111/96277) to enable USB debugging.

Comment: [Check my answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/248336/378661) for newer Android phones

Answer (score 0):

have you tried booting into safe mode?  it might boot with normal resolution and then you can try change the resolution settings back to normal.

[boot into safe mode LG G3](http://www.verizonwireless.com/support/knowledge-base-112843/)