# system ui not responding after changing screen density

Tags: cyanogenmod, twrp

I have cm12.1
I changed the lcd density to something low .then phone restarted ,and after restart I got message saying "system ui has stopped."
I couldn't change the LCD density back to normal 
so I made a backed up /data using twrp recovery. then I wiped it.
I want to restore that data and I think I got 2 options
1--I can restore /data and use adb to change build.prop myself ..or

2--I have the data.ext4.win file created by recovery. I can change build.prop file in the backup
.
my question is,how can I browse in adb as root user 
and or how can I open that data.ext4.win file (I have disabled md5 checking)

Comment: See if my answer helps out somehow: [Stuck in boot after changing dpi - Lenovo a7000](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/131556)

Comment: Rather than manually unpacking the backup created by TWRP, I advise you to restore the whole system to its original state and flash CyanogenMod again. Then, install Titanium Backup, which will let you browse your backup and manually select what apps and data to restore.

Comment: Still, if you want to manually fix the build.prop (which resides on /system, not on /data), you can start a rooted adb session by typing **adb root** from your computer's terminal, pull the build.prop with **adb pull /system/build.prop /path/where/to/put/the/file**, manually change the *ro.sf.lcd_density* field to its original value, and then push the file back on the device, with **adb push /path/to/the/fixed/file /system**.

Comment: I tried both of these methods but problem is not solved. there was no change made to the build.prop,I changed to.sf.LCD_density back to normal,  
even that didn't help.
there was an entry in /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/settings.db
I changed LCD density in global Field of database and pushed it back .
now phone is struck at cm logo.