# How to unset ROM Toolbox set device density

Tags: root-access, screen

I pretty much bricked the UI now with the build property editor's `ro.sf.lcd_density` setting. I first set it to mdpi (160) which made my UI elements tiny (should have made them bigger) and the keypad's back button was missing for whatever reason, so the only change I could make is to add a letter to make it high density (1160) - now it is totally unusable:

[image: screenshot]

How can I rid of this setting and get back to normal?

Comment: Do you've USB debugging enabled or a custom recovery installed or original build.prop file available or stock ROM's zip? Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/131556/96277

Comment: What's your default DPI?

Comment: 480dpi; @Firelord - thanks for the nice link, I upvoted you even though I ended up flashing a new ROM

Comment: Can you access the device via ADB and get a root shell? If so, try `setprop ro.sf.lcd_density 480`. If it works out, make sure to fix up your `build.prop` before booting the next time. If not, you could try booting into recovery and fix it from there: the `build.prop` is a plain text file, so you can edit it with e.g. `vi`.