# LG G4 infected with MyServices malware

Tags: malware, lg-g4

I have an app that has just appeared out of nowhere called **MyServices** which looks like a malware. It doesn't appear in the list of apps and I can't uninstall it. How can I get rid of it?
I have an LG G4 running Android *Lollipop 5.1*

Comment: Why can you not uninstall it? Consider elaborating on that part. Is the Android rooted? Can you give us its package name? (This may come handy: [View app's full package name?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28767))

Answer (score 0):

Try installing an antivirus like [Avast](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.avast.android.mobilesecurity) or [Malwarebytes](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.malwarebytes.antimalware).