# Disabling Samsung Applications without root permissions?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, rooting, samsung, samsung-galaxy-note-2

I currently have a Samsung Galaxy Note II (GT-N7105) which is not rooted and is running 4.4.2 Kitkat, while it still works pretty fast, sometimes if just freezes with all the processes.

I have though about rooting it so i can delete all the applications that might be using hidden processes and storage room but i have read that rooting it could also cause major problems if done incorrectly so i was looking for another way to delete these applications (Samsung Push Service, etc.) without rooting it, and if there is none can someone direct me to an almost fool-proof way to root it with Android 6.0 (or another, doesn't really matter).

Comment: The particular ones that you intend to disable, are you not able to disable them from Settings app -> Apps/Applications -> All apps -> your system app -> Disable? If not, then try my answer available [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/136282/96277). You would never be able to delete a system app without root access.

Comment: [This](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ospolice.packagedisablerpro&hl=en) Samsung-only app allows you to disable any system app without root. Only for Samsung devices; it takes advantage of a hidden TouchWiz API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to your application manager tab in settings, select the app you wish to disable and press disable to block any of the apps processes. This will not remove the app, but it will prevent the app from running or doing anything. The app icon will also disappear so it will be hidden, just as if you removed the app. If you want to delete the whole app, you need root and the free trial of titanium backup will delete all the files of the app.