# Saving contacts to SIM / view SIM contacts

Tags: contacts, sim-card, 7.1-nougat

I've just bought a new Android phone (Wileyfox Swift 2X) and updated to Android 7.1.2.

Up until now I have always saved my contacts to my SIM card, which saved me a great deal of trouble with past Android phones that had broken screens, as I only had to insert my SIM card in a new device and voila, all my contacts are there.

However, on Android 7.1.2, I am unable to view SIM contacts or save new contacts to the SIM card. My only option is a Gmail account (linked to the device) - which is not what I want. I am even unable to save new contacts to the device itself.

In the 'Contacts' app, the 'Contacts to display' menu item has 3 options:

- WhatsApp
- Google (....@gmail.com)
- Customize (no SIM options here either)

I'm pretty sure that in all my Android phones up until now I had a 'device' and 'SIM' option.

In the 'Contacts' app, I do have the option to import/export:

- Import from .vcf file
- Import from SIM card
- Export to SIM card
- Export to .vcf file
- Share all contacts

So for now, I imported my SIM contacts (to the GMail account), so I can use my device for now. However, I want to only store my contacts on the SIM card.

---

I've checked out some apps in the Google Play Store that read the SIM contacts and they work fine (although with ads) so this is not ideal.

Did they remove the SIM contacts option? Is there a way to enable it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This depends on the Contacts app, and every manufacturer can customize their built-in Contacts app. It might help to know [the package of the Contacts app](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28767/44325) to confirm which Contacts app this is about. Otherwise, 3rd-party Contacts apps might be the alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot specifically tell with your device, as I've never used it, but I can surely tell on **Samsung Galaxy Edge 7**, which runs on Nougat.

There, this option **available** under More options in Contacts, as per this [video](https://youtu.be/9mBx30UyN0o).

It may have been possible that your manufacturer has developed the User Interface in such a way that this is not supported, but Nougat OS clearly supports it.

Comment: Indeed, it's a little different on Nougat. As I said in my question, the 'contacts to diplay' screen only shows Gmail and WhatsApp as options unfortunately. I will contact Wileyfox and ask them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say anything specific to your device but in my Moto G5+ even i dont have any option of viewing or managing sim contacts but i did find a app that does so
It also have add/delete multiselect etc options

[SIMcardToolManager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keesadens.SIMcardToolManager)