# What is 'Launcher3' in Android Nougat?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, launcher, motorola-moto-g5

I was recently trying Microsoft's Arrow launcher and it was then I saw that the default launcher on my phone is called 'Launcher3'. Its icon resembles 16-bit icon.

[image]

From what I read, it is the name of default Google launcher. Is it?

Does my phone why virus or this is the default launcher from Google? I am using Moto G5 Plus.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Launcher3 is the default launcher in [AOSP Android](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher3/), and is the base behind many customized launchers - even Google's own Now Launcher (obsolete) and Pixel Launcher. Some manufacturers would leave the default name and icon in, but customize its appearance and behaviour nonetheless.

If still unsure, verify the package ID using one of the methods listed in [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28767/view-apps-full-package-name).

Comment: Google should have given it a better name. Launcher3? And that 16-bit icon?

Comment: It had been evolving from Launcher (up to Android 2.1 as I remember) to Launcher2 (2.2 all the way up to before KitKat) and then now Launcher3. I would say that along with the icon is just programmer's way of doing stuff - you aren't *supposed* to see them outside the Android Emulator (AVD, and now integrated in Android Studio, for developers either way) anyway.