# How to enable/disable apps using ADB (Android 8.x)?

Tags: applications, adb, samsung, 8.0-oreo, samsung-galaxy-a5

I cannot get apps enabled or disabled using ADB.

- Android: 8.0.0
- Device: Samsung Galaxy A520 (SM-A520F)

I don't have root access to my device.

To get the list of the disabled packages I use:

```
$ adb shell pm list packages -d
package:com.samsung.android.game.gamehome
package:com.microsoft.skydrive
package:com.google.android.webview
package:com.google.android.videos
package:flipboard.boxer.app
package:com.samsung.android.ststub
package:com.sec.android.emergencylauncher
package:com.samsung.android.dlp.service
package:com.samsung.upsmtheme
```

Q1: Oddly, this list doesn't seem to include the apps I really disabled in the Apps section:

- Briefing
- Google Play Movies & TV

Why is that?

Then I run through the list and enable every package, e.g.:

```
$ adb shell pm enable com.google.android.webview
Package com.google.android.webview new state: enabled
```

Q2: Despite some packages are reported as "enabled" they are still in the disabled list:

```
$ adb shell pm list packages -d | grep com.google.android.webview
package:com.google.android.webview
```

Why is that?

Q3: How can I get the list of packages that I myself disabled in the Apps section and how can I manage this list using ADB?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Our site has a nice search field. I've put the corresponding terms in, so you might wish to check [these posts](/search?q=pm+disable+hide). About the reported failure: could it have to do with permissions? Some `disable` commands, in my experience, require root power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q1: Oddly, this list doesn't seem to include the apps I really disabled in the Apps section:
>
> - Briefing
> - Google Play Movies & TV
>
> Why is that?

Your output already listed the two apps. `com.google.android.videos` for Google Play Movies and `flipboard.boxer.app` for Briefing app.

Optional: see [my answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/198096/96277) to know how to find an app's package name easily.

For your other issue:

This seems to be a problem in your ROM per se. My experiences with stock Android ROMs on Nexus 6 device and a near stock Android ROM on OnePlus 6 (Android 8.1.0) tell me this shouldn't happen.

Normally, the apps disabled using shell user are not listed in Settings app, but any app disabled by any means are listed in `pm list packages -d` or `cmd package list packages -d`.

Disabling and enabling an app without root access is simple. Run:

```
adb shell pm disable-user PACKAGE_NAME  # disables the app for the current user
adb shell pm enable PACKAGE_NAME        # enables the app for the user, regardless of how the app was disabled.
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, you were right about the identity of those 2 packages. (I personally find it confusing that on the one hand you cannot see a package's class in the UI and from another - there is no shell command to establish package title by its class.) As for the command `pm disable-user <package_name>` - it perfectly did its job, yeah. Now I can enable/disable packages from command line!