# Remove Google Play Services from no-root Android 8.1 phone

Tags: 8.1-oreo

How does user remove the stubborn 'Google Play Services' from the Android phone? Android 8.1 'Google Play Services' does not allow remove updates option. Why does 'Google Play Services' behave similarly like the Microsoft Edge web browser that is stubborn and can't be removed.

User buy the Android phone should not be denied from uninstall stock apps such as the notorious 'Google Play Services' that use data usage without user permission!

Please do not provide answers such as root the android phone because this question is about no-root phone (meaning the phone is not rooted). Also,  PoGO has new TOS that does not care about user privacy!

Comment: See https://android.stackexchange.com/a/204114/96277