# Google Pay is nowhere to be found

Tags: samsung, nfc, google-pay

The situation is pretty strange:
Google Play store tells me that Google Pay is not compatible with my device (Samsung S10), but **I know it is installed and I have used it in the past**.

When I click on NFC it allows me to choose Google Pay as preferred payment option, my bank app could set its debit card into Google Pay and I'm definitely able to pay by using my phone (I've done it multiple times).

But.. The app is nowhere to be shown. I tried to look for it in settings/apps but it is not there and I wouldn't know what else to do to find it (apart from a factory reset?)

Comment: This answer may help you https://android.stackexchange.com/a/204114/131553

Comment: @beeshyams thanks for the tip! I checked the whole list of installed packages and it seems that Google Pay is not installed (at least, nothing with 'pay' in the name apart from the *Samsung Payment Framework* )

Comment: No, that's not the way. Open the app url in your web browser and whatever is after `id`is the package name, for example, for Chrome `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome`, it is `com.android chrome`

Comment: @beeshyams ah nice! I was struggling in finding the package names. Also that one is not there. I ended up installing the APK from apkpure dot com. Now I finally have Google Pay.