# How can I identify which app in a certain category is installed on an Android device, to install it on another?

Tags: applications

I bought my old Android phone on a trip to China so some apps came from Chinese app stores and some came from Google's after I came back.

For apps that fit in a certain category, such as currency converters, how can I identify with certainty which exact such app is on a phone. By looking around the app and in the phone's preferences and settings, I can only find the name, which is pretty generic, and a version number.

Is there some kind of more unique identifier, some kind of ID, or some kind of link that's somewhere on all Android phones that will truly identify each app?

Comment: Android uses package name as a unique identifier, [View app's full package name?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28767) might help.

Comment: That does look helpful! Too bad they all seem to require an app or attaching hardware...