# How to get rid of grey error/alert message popup (toast)

Tags: applications, 9.0-pie, toast-notifications

I keep getting grey pop-up error messages from an essential app I don't want to uninstall ("xDrip+: No sensor found"). The messages keep displaying outside of the app which is annoying. Is there a way to disable those messages?

I tried finding that out myself but I couldn't even find what this element is called. Any help, even just saying what this message type is called by Android would be a step forward.

I'm quite surprised that apps are allowed to display those intrusive messages whenever they want.

edit: The alert is called a toast.

[image]

Comment: xDrip+ is an app, most likely you have it installed: https://github.com/NightscoutFoundation/xDrip

Comment: Hi Robert, I stated I don't want to uninstall the app. I'm looking for a way to disable its toasts (at least outside the app itself) without having to uninstall it. The toasts feel very crude and more like last century UI to me - so I'm surprised they are actually part of Android.

Comment: Setup [tag:adb] in your PC, and issue this command: `adb shell appops set PKG_NAME TOAST_WINDOW deny` to prevent toasts from reappearing. Replace PKG_NAME with the package name of the xdrip+ app. To find it, follow my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/198096/96277).

Comment: @Cornelius It is an open source project. You can simply create an issue [here](https://github.com/NightscoutFoundation/xDrip/issues) and describe the problem you have and how annoying this toast is.

Comment: @Firelord: This sounds great, I'll have a try!
Robert: Good point, I will do that, too. Maybe they can simply add an option to disable the toasts from within the app to the notifications menu. Bit of an XY-problem ;)

Comment: @Firelord Where did you find this command? Is there also a command to check the current status of the app (of this configuration), too?

Comment: @androiddeveloper through curiosity. A new Android was released. Decided to dig into system binaries and got my hands on it. XDA might have been another source. Don't remember for sure. As for appops configuration of a  package, the command appops takes other arguments too. Just type 'adb shell appops' to see them. To see appops config of a package, type 'adb shell appops get PKG_NAME'

Comment: @Firelord Thank you. It's not documented anywhere? From which version of Android is it available?

Comment: @androiddeveloper the executable and the underlying functionality of permissions was introduced in Android 5. But it had issues in working. Since Android 5.1 it seems to be working fine. Over the years it has improved with more arguments available. No, there is no documentation available. Searching adb shell appops actually leads to its source code! As for which ops can be changed, I also had to search that in another source code once!

Comment: @androiddeveloper  The backend AppopsManager documentation is here though. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AppOpsManager The oldest api support seems to be from Android 4.4. I don't know much though so that's all I can help. :)

Comment: @Firelord Interesting. Do you think it can grant/deny special permissions, such as accessibility, admin, ... Maybe also setting as default app of something? BTW the link is dead.

Comment: @androiddeveloper I have fixed that link. Try that again. Special permissions, I don't know about. The [source of AppOpsManager.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/android11-mainline-release/core/java/android/app/AppOpsManager.java) (android 11) does mention certain capabilities related to Accessibility. You can see for yourself if it does have support or not. As for admin, no. It is manipulated through dpm binary when using adb. http://adbcommand.com/adbshell/dpm

Comment: @Firelord Wait you know how to grant/deny both?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123585/discussion-between-firelord-and-android-developer).