# Sleeping Cat, Mint Room, and Giraffe. Anyone know what these files are?

Tags: settings, internal-storage

In trying to make room in storage on my LG phone, I ran across 3 "apps" or files that I have never downloaded nor heard of and I have no idea how to find out what they are. **Sleeping Cat**, **Mint Room**, and **Giraffe** are their names, my question is if anyone knows what they could be and if I can delete them safely.

Comment: Please check their package name by following [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28767/44325)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the location of this files and also the filetype, but you can try to rename the files and reboot and see what happend, if you face any problems by using an app you can rename it to the original filename.