# What is the Root app in Android and why is it connecting to the Internet?

Tags: system-apps

The Root app is showing up in ProtectStar Firewall, but not the Settings app list with System Apps visible. It tried to connect to 99.86.100.101, an AWS (Amazon Web Services) IP address according to that app's log. What is it doing?

Comment: Give us its package name. Its name is useless to us. Android doesn't come with any package named Root. Use my answer if you need help in finding package name. https://android.stackexchange.com/a/198096/96277

Comment: You probably refer to the Android system user 1000. This has several components "reaching out" – for example for name resolution (`nslookup` alike), time services (NTP), Captive Portal Check and more. Without the full entry it's hard to say what it might be doing at AWS. The IP you give belongs to Cloudfront, which is a CDN, so it can be many things.