# Need to move data from a specific app from LG Q7+ to Samsung

Tags: data-transfer

I have data on my LG Q7+ phone that I need to move to a Samsung Galaxy S22+. The app on the phone is called Note (`notes.notebook.memo.pad.color.notepad.locker`).

I can transfer the app, but the data does not go with it. I have tried Smart Switch, MyPhoneExplorer, and a couple of other backups. Google backup will not back it up because Google says it is a questionable app. The app is also no longer on the Play Store. Neither phone is rooted.

How to move the data?

Please help,

Thank you

Comment: What is the package name of the app (see [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28767/2241) how to get it) ? If the app disallows backup and has no export function and no own cloud sync then you can not access the data on an unrooted device.

Comment: Thank you for answering. The package name is: notes.notebook.memo.pad.color.notepad.locker
The app allowed backup to google but google has disallowed it because they say it is a security risk.