# APK backup with data Anybooks app

Tags: samsung, backup, data-recovery, apk

Non-techie here. I have a Samsung Galaxy J7 Pro and installed the Anybooks app which is now discontinued. Since I had downloaded 1 GB of books, I need to migrate the app and data to a new phone.

The Anybooks app stores user data in the cache. I have tried APK backup apps and Samsung Smart Switch, but only the APK is backed up without the crucial user data.

How can I back up the app and data?

Comment: Looks like there are a few apps containing the name "Anybooks". Is the app mentioned in the answer the correct one? Otherwise, you might want to [find its package name](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28767/44325) and mention it for clarity.

Comment: Yes it is the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry but the app [AnyBooks](https://apkpure.com/anybooks-free-books-free-reading/anybooks.free.books.novels.ebooks.download.gp) (anybooks.free.books.novels.ebooks.download.gp) has the entry `android:allowBackup="false"` in it's `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Your Samsung j7 pro should run Android 9 which means it should respect this entry for adb backup and backup to Google Drive/Cloud.

As you have already tried Samsung smart switch this means there is no way to backup or migrate the data, unless your phone is already rooted.

Note that rooting the old phone is not an option because in the rooting process all user data will be erased in a way which makes recovery of the data impossible.

Comment: Thank you Robert..have a51s samsung phone..Will it be the same scenario. So can nandroid or titanium pro  backup work ?

Comment: @arul As Titanium requires root this should work (unless the app uses AndrodKeyStore to store the decryption keys in case of the downloaded books are encrypted). Note that if you make a backup with root you also need root to restore it on a different phone.