# What is system app called "iconnect" in huawei Y9 2019

Tags: applications, huawei, system-apps, phone-app, emui

My phone is Huawei Y9 2019, EMUI 8.2.0
Android 8.2.1

In my app list, I found app called "iconnect" with green android icon, I'm not sure it is pre-installed system app from Huawei or not.

So, I have some questions

1. Does anyone who use Y9 2019 has this "Iconnect" app in app list?
2. What does this app be used for?
3. Is it a pre-installed system app from Huawei or not?

Thank you

Comment: In its app info, does the button say "Uninstall" or "Disable"? If it can only be disabled, then it's considered a system app (packaged into EMUI). Whether it's from Huawei or a 3rd-party partner, we probably need more info, like [the package name](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28767/44325).