# Application named Athena, green, circular, filled, black. Malware?

Tags: applications, malware

I was looking for software to sync my Oppo A15s and PC. So I got to a software named My Phone Explorer. Both my phone and PC are working smoothly and efficiently. There is no problem in syncing, but one fine day, I was just checking the file section of My Phone Explorer, in which I found a subsection named Applications.

In this application section, I found the list of all applications which are system applications as well as which I have installed from Play Store or by side loading. Now, the problem starts in this list: there are a few applications named "Athena", "green", "circular", "filled", and a few more; which I do not remember that I have installed. When I try to delete them, there is a failure notice.

My Phone Explorer can export these as .APK. When I googled them, mostly they were talking about Windows desktop malware. So, can anybody enlighten me on what these are, and if they are malware, how to remove them?

[image: First and sixth application]
[image: System specification]

Comment: As you are talking about system apps, would you mind telling us what Android phone you use (system apps are device specific) and what Android version it runs? Also a screenshot showing the apps you mention would be good.

Comment: Otherwise, consider [finding the package names](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28767/44325) and stating them here. App names are far from unique in Android.

Comment: Nevermind, I found a list of ColorOS 7 pre-packaged apps on [XDA Forums](https://xdaforums.com/t/x50-5g-china-realmi-ui-1-0-debloating-october-2020.4171239/post-83621045) which includes these apps.

Answer (score 1):

****GAINING MORE KNOWLEDGE IS SIMPLE ANSWER.****

When I checked on andriod debugg bridge with
`adb shell`
and then
`pm list packages`
with following output
[image: Partial output of command pm list packages]

Now checking the list I come to know that Athena,green,circular,filled,black are system packages. Thanks to Andrew.T & Robert.